# Swift 5: Why the Index out of range error appears?

Tags: arrays, swift, indexoutofrangeexception

I have two arrays that I am going to include in an array with object instances. When I try to do this, I get an error that the Index is out of range.

My code is below. I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

let mealName = ["Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Snack", "Supper", "Snack", "Breakfast", "Snack", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Supper", "Snack", "Breakfast", "Snack", "Dinner", "Snack", "Snack", "Snack", "Breakfast", "Snack", "Lunch", "Snack", "Snack", "Snack", "Breakfast", "Snack", "Lunch", "Snack", "Snack", "Snack", "Snack"]

let mealCalories = [725.03, 539.44, 849.49, 956.53, 267.18, 567.17, 353.47, 387.12, 700.76, 62.87, 857.35, 176.56, 123.79, 16.74, 813.74, 858.23, 127.26, 448.19, 932.62, 60.22, 880.55, 58.85, 78.48, 21.5, 564.74, 190.75, 911.01, 67.47, 81.44, 25.35, 954.94, 45.75, 858.71, 61.7, 189.75, 72.54, 75.84]


struct Meal {
    var mealName: String
    var mealCalories: Double
}

var meals = [Meal]()

for i in 0..<37 {
    meals[i].mealName = mealName[i]
    meals[i].mealCalories = mealCalories[i]
}
```

[image]

Comment: The i is accessing an index that is not in the array.

Comment: Why not? I have initialized the array - var meals = [Meal]()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have initialized the meals array but it is empty and doesn't have length. Therefore, when you refer to meals[i] it raises an error. You can do something like this:

```
var meals: [Meal] = [Meal](repeating: Meal(mealName: "", mealCalories: 0.0), count: 37)
```

Then you can refer to meals[i] (0<= i <37).

If you want to start with an empty array you can add elements to it:

```
var meals = [Meal]()
```

Then:

```
for i in 0..<37 {
    let meal = Meal(mealName: mealName[i], mealCalories: mealCalories[i])
    meals.append(meal)
}
```

In this case, the length of meals will grow as i grows.

Comment: i.e., it turns out that if the array is initialized with an empty value, then this empty value does not have an index?

Comment: Empty means it doesn't have any elements. In Swift you can empty an array (e.g. myArray) by calling myArray.removeAll() or setting myArray = [].

Comment: @maxMas You cannot access an element at an index (via a subscript) if the array does not already contain something at that index, even if you are trying to insert something into that index. For any array, you can only index at `i < array.count`, and if the array is empty, `array.count == 0`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping me figure it out. I appreciate this very much!

Comment: The edited answer might help too.

Comment: Wow! I just saw your edited answer. This is a very interesting solution. Thank you!

Comment: @maxMas There's some useful terminology that can help clear this up. An array has a `capacity`, which indicates how large the underlying buffer is. Of that capacity, only the first `count` "slots" are used. The remaining are available for use, but aren't members of the array (yet).

Answer (score 2):

## Just avoid the parallel arrays

You already have a `Meal` struct, which begs the question: Why not define your meals directly?

```swift
struct Meal {
    // Don't prefix the properties with "meal".
    // It leads to pointless code like "someMeal.mealName".
    // You already know it's a meal by the type.
    let name: String
    let calories: Double
}

let meals = [
    Meal(name: "Breakfast", calories: 725.03),
    Meal(name: "Lunch",     calories: 539.44),
    Meal(name: "Dinner",    calories: 849.49),
    Meal(name: "Breakfast", calories: 956.53),
    Meal(name: "Lunch",     calories: 267.18),
    Meal(name: "Dinner",    calories: 567.17),
    Meal(name: "Breakfast", calories: 353.47),
    Meal(name: "Lunch",     calories: 387.12),
    Meal(name: "Dinner",    calories: 700.76),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  62.87),
    Meal(name: "Supper",    calories: 857.35),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories: 176.56),
    Meal(name: "Breakfast", calories: 123.79),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  16.74),
    Meal(name: "Lunch",     calories: 813.74),
    Meal(name: "Dinner",    calories: 858.23),
    Meal(name: "Supper",    calories: 127.26),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories: 448.19),
    Meal(name: "Breakfast", calories: 932.62),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  60.22),
    Meal(name: "Dinner",    calories: 880.55),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  58.85),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  78.48),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  21.50),
    Meal(name: "Breakfast", calories: 564.74),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories: 190.75),
    Meal(name: "Lunch",     calories: 911.01),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  67.47),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  81.44),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  25.35),
    Meal(name: "Breakfast", calories: 954.94),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  45.75),
    Meal(name: "Lunch",     calories: 858.71),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  61.70),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories: 189.75),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  72.54),
    Meal(name: "Snack",     calories:  75.84),
]
```

This way you don't have to fidget around to find out which string in one array "lines up" with the double in the other array.

## If the parallel arrays must stay

(e.g. they come from an API you don't control)

There are several huge issues:

1. You're hard-coding the number of meals, when it's entirely possible that they might change in the future.

   An array already stores its own count, and hard-coding that count elsewhere is introducing a split source of truth. The risk here is that they go out of sync:

   - If the new meal names/calories are added but you forget to update the `37`, then you'll be missing those meals from your result.
   - If some meal names/calories are removed, then your `37` will be too large and cause an out of bounds error.
2. You're indexing into an empty array rather than appending

Luckily, these are easily fixable!

Here's a progression of improvements:

1. Fix the indexing past the end, and use `append` instead:

   ```swift
   var meals = [Meal]()
   for i in 0..<37 {
       meals.append(Meal(name: mealNames[i], calories: mealCalories[i]))
   }
   ```
2. Un-hardcode the last index:

   ```swift
   assert(mealNames.count == mealCalories.count,
       "Config error! The names and calories should match up one for one!")

   var meals = [Meal]()

   for i in 0..<meanNames.count {
       meals.append(Meal(name: mealNames[i], calories: mealCalories[i]))
   }
   ```
3. Un-harcode the start index:

   ```swift
   assert(mealNames.count == mealCalories.count, ...)

   var meals = [Meal]()

   for i in mealNames.indices {
       meals.append(Meal(name: mealNames[i], calories: mealCalories[i]))
   }
   ```
4. Forget the indices entirely! Just use [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/zip(_:_:)):

   ```swift
   assert(mealNames.count == mealCalories.count, ...)

   var meals = [Meal]()

   for (name, calories) in zip(mealNames, mealCalories) {
       meals.append(Meal(name: name, calories: calories))
   }
   ```
5. Iterating over an input, transforming it, and producing a new array is just a map operation.

   ```swift
   assert(mealNames.count == mealCalories.count, ...)

   let meals = zip(mealNames, mealCalories).map { name, calories in
       Meal(name: name, calories: calories))
   }
   ```

   Bonus: now that `meals` isn't constructed via repeated mutation, we can now make it a `let` constant!

Comment: You're right. That's exactly what I wanted to do. I just wanted to do it not manually, but to automate this process.

Comment: @maxMas I just put a `print` statement in the `for` loop, and used code to generate this code :) `print("    Meal(name: \"\(name)\", calories: \(calories)),")`

Comment: @maxMas Although even if you did have to do this manually, it's *much* easier to write out the structs by hand than it is to waste your time playing the "comma counting game" to line stuff up. And then invariably at some point you'll want to add a third field, and it all becomes a mess.

Comment: "I just put a print statement in the for loop," - it's brilliant! This is what I needed to do!